# Why when 404.blade.php is opened I got error that $slot variable not found?

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have defined resources/views/errors/404.blade.php file in livewire 2, but I found that
In layout file line with
{{ $slot }}
raise error that this variable not found.
In my routes/web.php I defines rotes to livewire components , like

```
Route::get('/register', App\Http\Livewire\Register::class)->name('Register');
```

as 404.blade.php  is not related component I suppose it raise error, but how that can be fixed ?

**UPDATED PART :**

My resources/views/errors/404.blade.php has no any slot defined :

```
<div class="container"  id="404_container">

    <div class="content">
        <x-h1 class=" error_text flex items-center justify-center flex-nowrap my-4 py-4">
            You entered invalid url !
        </x-h1>

        <div class="flex items-center justify-center m-5">
            <a class="cursor-pointer" href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I do not know is it valid content. I create my app with --jet option and livewire selected...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to share some more pieces of your code, the route doesn't give us much when the error is in a view. 404 might mean that your route model bindings didn't find its resource, and so Laravel intercepts the exception and renders the 404 view. Sounds like you have a slot in your 404 view, that probably should be removed

Comment: Could you please take a look at UPDATED PART

Comment: Ok, then it might be in your layout? Its really hard to keep guessing without seeing the actual error (with line-numbers and whatnot).